# Explanation for one line if statement behaviour?

Tags: c#, behavior

Example code:

```
int hour = 0;
bool saveData = true;

if(hour > 0) doSomeMethod(); saveData = false;
```

In the code above, saveData will always be set to false, yet doSomeMethod() won't be fired. I figured that the compiler treats the semi-colon after doSomeMethod() as an indicator to move to the next statement, ignoring that it's on the same line as the if statement. What's the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: that's why it's always better to wrap your if statement in code blocks {}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `if` statement can contain either a single statement, or a code block. Once the compiler finds the `;` it ends the `if`.

Your code above is equivalent to:

```
if (hour > 0)
    doSomeMethod();
saveData = false;
```

What you want is:

```
if (hour > 0)
{
    doSomeMethod();
    saveData = false;
}
```

or:

```
if (hour > 0) { doSomeMethod(); saveData = false; }
```

Comment: This was the answer I'm looking for, in other words: An if statement can contain either a SINGLE statement, or a code block.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: No, an "if" statement can contain *a single statement*, period. **A code block *is* a single statement.** (Note that the single statement may not be a labelled statement or a local declaration statement.)

Answer (score 4):

C# ignores newlines, just as C and its other descendants, and uses `;` to separate statements.
Your code is completely equivalent to

```
int hour = 0;
bool saveData = true;

if(hour > 0)
    doSomeMethod();
saveData = false;
```

which is better style, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

In C# an if statement can either be:

```
if(expression) statement;
```

or

```
if(expression) { statement1; ... statementN; }
```

You're code's lack of braces makes it the former, thus your guess is correct.